# PKAddPassButton shows wrong title on device with iOS 16

Tags: swift, iphone, passkit, apple-wallet

PKAddPassButton shows unlocalised title when I run the app on real device with iOS 16. The title is shown as "ADD_PASS_BUTTON_TITLE". It's correct if I run the same build on simulator (I see the title as "Add to Apple Wallet") and also on physical device with iOS 15 it works fine. But wrong title on iOS 16. Does anyone know what the reason could be?

Here is my code:
`var applePayButton: UIButton = { let button = PKAddPassButton(addPassButtonStyle: .blackOutline) button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false return button }()`
And this is the result on iphone with iOS 16.x:
[Wrong title for PKAddPassButton button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1HyC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on physical devices.(iOS 16.5 and 16.6.1) But it work just fine.

Could you provide any more clues on how you add button to the parent view?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var applePayButton: UIButton = {
        let button = PKAddPassButton(addPassButtonStyle: .blackOutline)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.addSubview(backgroundView)
        backgroundView.addSubview(applePayButton)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure. I actually add the button to a container view and add it to a stack view. Also my project is actually turned to framework and been used in a parent app (I don't know if this can cause the issue). So my tests are on the parent app which is using my project as a framework being installed though pods.